# Does the prohibition of taking revenge - [לא תקום] - also apply to a 3rd party?

Tags: revenge-nekama

A. Does the prohibition of taking revenge - [לא תקום] - also apply to a 3rd party, or only to the person who was offended?

B. If the person who was offended tells someone else to take revenge of the offender, would either, or both of them, (or neither) be guilty of taking revenge?

Comment: Part B is a multi-faceted question. Would the fact that the revenge is being taken by request of the offended person deem it as forbidden revenge?  Is it considered as if the defended person himself took revenge? [maybe because of איסור אמירה, of which there is a discussion whether it applies only to a goy or also to telling another yid). Is the 3rd person guilty of his own aveira of nekamah. Do we say אין שליח לדבר עבירה?

Comment: The person would not be taking revenge but would be avenging.

Comment: @ezra Hence my question, Is he guilty of transgressing the aveira of taking revenge?

Comment: Sounds like something the מנחת חנוך would write about. I recommend checking there.